# doesn't solving for linear independence require the use of linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

wouldn't that be circular logic?

what I mean is

-solving linear independence is an earlier topic

-solving systems of linear equations is a later topic

But to do linear independence requires solving systems of linear equations which we haven't covered yet.

---

For example, determine if the set

$$ S = {\{(1, −1, 2),(1, −2, 1),(1, 1, 4)}\} $$

of three vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ is independent or dependent.

Is there a nontrivial solution to the vector equation
x(1, −1, 2) + y(1, −2, 1) + z(1, 1, 4) = (0, 0, 0)?

Solve the system of homogeneous linear equations

x + y + z = 0

−x −2y + z = 0

2x + y + 4z = 0

---

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear independence of vectors is a basic concept *defined* independently in ealier topic and which requires, in general, the solution of a homogeneous system of linear equation to be *checked*.

There is a link between the two concept but there is not any circular logic in that.